# Connection String of Windows Azure in php

Tags: php, azure

I have such a connection statement to connect the blob storage I've created in windows azure.

```
$connectionString = 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=<accountname>;AccountKey=<secret key>';
$echo "1";

$blobRestProxy = ServicesBuilder::getInstance()->createBlobService($connectionString);
$echo "2";
```

When I put this, "1" is written, but "2" isn't.

Does it mean, $blobRestProxy isn't working?

I try to create a container in my blob storage, but it fails.

How can I fix the problem?

Thanks.

**UPDATES:**

This is the link the picture which shows the inside of public_html

http://picpaste.com/2-FjXF4Kpo.jpg

These are the links of the picture which shows the inside of website folder

http://picpaste.com/3-CReA0E72.jpg

http://picpaste.com/4-Tjvv3Br7.jpg

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>more</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">      
<meta name="description" content="Description goes here">
<meta name="keywords" content="Keywords goes here">     

<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/preview.css" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>-->

<!--[if lt IE 8]>
    <div style=' clear: both; text-align:center; position: relative;z-index:100;'>
        <a href="http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/products/ie/home?ocid=ie6_countdown_bannercode"><img src="http://storage.ie6countdown.com/assets/100/images/banners/warning_bar_0000_us.jpg" border="0" height="42" width="820" alt="You are using an outdated browser. For a faster, safer browsing experience, upgrade for free today." /></a>
    </div>
<![endif]-->

</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <section>
            <div class="dynamicContent">
        <!--content -->
        <?php
            $server = "tcp:t656iqht6v.database.windows.net,1433";
            $user = "saitarslanboun@t656iqht6v";
            $pwd = "Uj8PfOf4";
            $db = "misbounstashnew_db";

            $conn = sqlsrv_connect($server, array("UID"=>$user, "PWD"=>$pwd, "Database"=>$db));

            if($conn === false){
            die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors()));
            }
        ?>


        <?php 
            echo '<h3>'.$_GET['course'].'</h3>';
        ?>

        <?php
            echo "1";
            require_once 'WindowsAzure.php';
            echo "2";
            use WindowsAzure\Common\ServicesBuilder;
            echo "3";
            use WindowsAzure\Blob\Models\CreateContainerOptions;
            echo "4";
            use WindowsAzure\Blob\Models\PublicAccessType;
            echo "5";
            use WindowsAzure\Common\ServiceException;
            echo "6";
            $connectionString = 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=misbounstashnew;AccountKey=o5uC6pxyUuLTbg4MOTunrzvqw0YzzcP90yyJuNjoue8PT2Rx8eIEZ/ZE1dnqMdsv1Ouvp35Qph5TjmCNiBya3A==';
            echo "7"; 
            $blobRestProxy = ServicesBuilder::getInstance()->createBlobService($connectionString);
            echo "8";
            if ($blobRestProxy) {echo "success_blobRestProxy";}
            if (!$blobRestProxy) {echo "fail_blobRestProxy";}
            $createContainerOptions = new CreateContainerOptions(); 

            try 
            {
                // Create container.
                $blobRestProxy->createContainer("mycontainer", $createContainerOptions);
            }
            catch(ServiceException $e)
            {
                // Handle exception based on error codes and messages.
                // Error codes and messages are here: 
                // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179439.aspx
                $code = $e->getCode();
                $error_message = $e->getMessage();
                echo $code.": ".$error_message."<br />";
            }

        ?>

        <!--content end -->
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
  <script>
    $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({animation_speed:'normal',theme:'dark',social_tools:false,allow_resize: true,default_width: 500,default_height: 344});    
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So Gaurav, actually I'm really hopeful that I will get the answer from you. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your code it is not clear if you have imported appropriate Azure libraries (not sure if this is the right terminology). I tried something like the following and it worked for me:

```
<?php
require_once 'WindowsAzure.php';
use WindowsAzure\Common\ServicesBuilder;
try {

$connectionString = 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=account name;AccountKey=account key';
echo "1";

$blobRestProxy = ServicesBuilder::getInstance()->createBlobService($connectionString);
echo "2";


} catch(ServiceException $e){
  // Handle exception based on error codes and messages.
  // Error codes and messages are here: 
  // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179446.aspx
  $code = $e->getCode();
  $error_message = $e->getMessage();
  echo $code.": ".$error_message."<br />";
}
?>
```

Screenshot of how things look on my computer:

[image]

Comment: Sorry for delay Gaurav, I was outside. Now I will try it.

Comment: Actually it's failed again. I think I've installed the libraries. But I'm not sure I've install to a wrong directory.

Comment: Since I don't do PHP development on the regular basis, I have just copied all the Azure SDK related files into the directory where I write sample PHP code. Please see the screenshot in my answer above.

Comment: I will try now Gaueav :)

Comment: Gaurav, what about test folders?

Comment: I have only Windows Azure folder.

Comment: Can you share your complete code and the file structure where Azure SDK is installed and from where you're running the php application (you can update the question itself).

Comment: Just a little time more, I will share now :) ı had a problem in saving screenshots :)

Comment: There should be another place to share all the screenshots I think. :)

Comment: So I looked at the screenshots and the code sample. Can you tell me the directory name in which the code is located. I'm looking at this picture.

Comment: ahh sorry :) the code is written in course.php file :)

Comment: Trying changing `require_once 'WindowsAzure.php';` to `require_once 'WindowsAzure/WindowsAzure.php';` or `require_once 'WindowsAzure\WindowsAzure.php';` in your code and see if that makes the difference.

Comment: I just did `require_once 'WindowsAzure\WindowsAzure.php';` in the code you posted and it is working fine for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54874/discussion-between-gaurav-mantri-and-hasan-sait-arslan).